# Retaining select box based values on page refresh

Tags: php, javascript

i have problem in drop down select menu from mysql and database

whenever i select the value from drop down select value page reload and page refresh and then return to option select option?

```
function getComboB(sel) { 

var roomtype=document.getElementById("roomtype");
var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
checkin.action = "checkin.php?item_combo="+value+"";
checkin.submit();

}



<select name="roomtype" id="roomtype" style="width:150px;"  onchange="getComboB(this)">

  <option><--Select--> </option>


       $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM roomtype order by id");
      while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
      {

    $val2=$row['id'];

    ?>
     <option  value="<?=$val2;?>"  <? if ($roomtype  == $val2) { echo "selected='selected'"; }?> > <?=$row['roomtype'];?> </option>


      <?php }?>


    </select>
```

Comment: And another bad formatted question!. Common people, if you're asking a question your job is to make sure it's properly formatted, is for your own good, the better the question the more people will be interested in at least taking a quick look.

Comment: do you have the solution of my this problem ?

Comment: Maybe I do, don't know... See I was editing our question but it was such a mess that I just posted the above comment and left it as it is. You're not getting enough attention because people see a lazy question and they get lazy too and move on.

Answer (score 1):

In short, I'd agree the question is rather painfully formatted.

Refreshing doesn't actually hold on to any values because you never submitted. Store the value via cookie or callback to the server to store it in the session. As for displaying here is another option.

---

Pass the selected option and select it with javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var theValue= "<?php echo "YourSelected Value"?> " // Or fetch from cookie.
$("#roomtype").find("select:eq(2)").find("option[value="+theValue+']').attr('selected','selected');
});
```